# How to stop reading from keyboard once a signal is handled?

Tags: c, linux, signals, fgets

I'm writing a program where the SIGINT signal is handled the first time it is sent, but set to default after that. So, for example, I have this:

```
static volatile int stop_terminating = 1;

void handler(int dummy) {
    stop_terminating = 0;
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    char input[256];
    while(1){
        if(stop_terminating == 0){
            // reset the action of the signal to default
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
            printf("Message sent.\n");
            // increment counter so it doesn't enter this condition again
            stop_terminating++;
        }
        printf("User input:\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        // In this stage, I wanna press CTRL+C and print a message, stopping the fgets
        // but what happens is: I press CTRL+C, the signal is catched, but fgets
        // is still asking for an input, and after I send something, the my message is printed
        // because it looped through the while(1) again.
    }
}
```

How can I stop fgets from asking for an input and just print the message and then ask again for an input?

Comment: `volatile` is not sufficient for multithreaded programming. Use atomics.

Comment: I actually don't know how to do that. I've been struggling to get to this point and I know some things just partially.

Comment: @Olaf: signals are not threads.  `volatile` is sufficient.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I wonder why there is `sig_atomic_t` with additional guarantees then. Interestingly this type existed _before_ C11's atomics support already. Note: `volatile` does not guarantee atomic access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux manual page for signals says that

> **Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers**
>
> If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:
>
> - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or
> - the call fails with the error `EINTR`.
>
> Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and whether or not the signal handler was established using the `SA_RESTART` flag (see `sigaction`(2)).

You may use either the `siginterrupt()` function together with `signal()`, or use `sigaction()` instead of `signal()` for registering your signal handler, in order to disable restarting a `read()` system call after a signal.

Note however that `fgets()` from the C library might call `read()` multiple times until a newline character is found, therefore you may also need to switch to using the lower-level functions instead of `stdio.h` APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you close stdin fgets will return immediately, then you can try to open stdin again. This is weird but can work as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You get a NULL from fgets when it reaches EOF. From the keyboard, that's usually signalled with CTRL-D (Linux/Unix/MacOS X) or CTRL-Z (DOS/Windows and I think MacOS before X)

Comment: This doesn't help with signal handling, which is the point of the question.

Comment: CTRL+D is not actually a signal, so that doesn't help me in this case. But I already solved it, thanks anyway.