# How to stop a thread reading stdin in a C++ Linux console application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin, nonblocking

I am writing a console application that accepts input (one-line commands) from `stdin`. This application reads input in a dedicated thread, all input is stored in a queue and later processed by the main thread in a safe way. When the *exit* command is entered by the user, it is intercepted by the input thread which stops listening for new input, the thread is joined into the main one, and the application stops as requested.

Now I am containerizing this application, but I still want to be able to attach to the container and input commands from `stdin`, so I specified `tty` and `stdin_open` to be `true` in my docker compose service file, and that did the trick.

But I also want docker compose to be able to gracefully stop the application, so I decided to implement `sigTerm()` in my application so that it can receive the signal from docker compose and gracefully stop, however I'm stuck on that part, because the input thread is blocking while waiting for input on `stdin`. I can properly receive the signal, that's not at all the point here, but I'm looking for a way to be able to properly stop my containerized application while still being able to input commands from the keyboard.

My application could be simplified like that :

```cpp
void gracefulStop() {
  while (getThreadCount() > 1) { // this function exists somewhere else.
    if (userInputThread.joinable()) {
      userInputThread.join();
      removeFromThreadCount(); // this function exists somewhere else.
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  exit(SUCCESS);
}

void sigTerm(int s) {
  // Maybe do some stuff here, but what...

  gracefulStop();
}

void userInputLoopThreadFunc() {
  addToThreadCount(); // this function exists somewhere else.
  while (keepGoing) {
    char buf[4096];
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
      break; // we couldn't read from stdin, stop trying.
    }
    std::string input = std::string(buf); // we received a command
    // Intercept exit command
    if (input.starts_with("exit")) {
      keepGoing = false;
    }
    // IRL there's thread safety 
    userInputQueue.push(input); // this will be processed by mainLoop() later
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Register the signal
  signal(SIGTERM, sigTerm);

  // Begin listening to user input
  userInputThread = std::thread(&userInputLoopThreadFunc, this);

  // this mainLoop function contains the core of the application
  // as well as the processing code of the user input
  mainLoop();

  // if mainLoop function returned, we received the 'exit' command
  gracefulStop();
}
```

I've read multiple question/answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171132/non-blocking-console-input-c) about non-blocking user input (the accepted answer advises to use a dedicated thread for input, which is what I am doing), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012278/stop-reading-from-stdin) about how to stop reading stdin, and the accepted answer seems promising but :

- using ncurses for what I'm trying to do seems really overkill
- If using `select()` and the timeout mechanism described, what would happen if the timeout occurs while typing a command?

Also I've read about the c++20 `jthread` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) :

> The class jthread represents a single thread of execution. It has the same general behavior as std::thread, except that jthread automatically rejoins on destruction, and can be cancelled/stopped in certain situations.

But I'm not sure that would help me here.

I'm thinking about multiple possibilities to solve my issue :

- Find a way to send a newline character to the `stdin` of my application without user interaction, would be hackish if at all possible but would probably unblock `fgets`.
- Kill the thread, I understand killing a thread is considered a bad practice, but since the only thing I'm doing here is stopping the application, maybe I can live with that, would there be any side effect? How would I do that?
- Rewriting user input in another way (unknown to me yet, `jthread`, something else?) that would allow `sigTerm()` to stop the application.
- Maybe use ncurses (would that really help me to stop the application by receiving a signal?)
- Go with `select()` and the timeout mechanism and live with the risk of an interrupted input
- Give up on user input and have some vacation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close `stdin` in your signal handler.   `fgets` will then return immediately (and presumably, return `NULL`).

The good news is that `close` is on the [list of functions that are safe to call from a signal handler](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (it's a pretty restrictive list).  Happy days.

There's an [alternative based around `EINTR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241779/how-to-stop-reading-from-keyboard-once-a-signal-is-handled), but it looks messy since you don't know for certain that `fgets` will actually return when it gets it.

Also, closing `stdin` should still work should you switch to using `cin` and `getline`, which would definitely improve your code (*).  That probably returns and sets [`badbit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085151/c-ifstream-failbit-and-badbit) when you close `stdin`, although the code can be made more robust than by checking for that alone.  Perhaps just set a (`volatile`) flag in your signal handler and test that.

(*) Because `getline` can read into a `std::string`, which means it can read arbitrary long lines without worrying about allocating a fixed-size buffer that is 'big enough'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as accepted as soon as I had a chance to implement it. And I will definitely follow your advice about stdin vs cin.